# Ground state degeneracy of $\hat{H}= \sum_{i=1}^{L-1} \mathbf{\hat{S}}_i\cdot \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{i+1}$, given a possible ground state

Tags: hilbert-space, tensor-calculus, ground-state

Consider $\hat{H}= \sum_{i=1}^{L-1} \mathbf{\hat{S}}_i\cdot \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{i+1}$ where $$ \mathbf{\hat{S}}_i\cdot \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{i+1} = 1_1\otimes\cdots\otimes 1_{i-1}\otimes \mathbf{\hat{S}}_i\otimes \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{i+1} \otimes 1_{i+2}\otimes\cdots\otimes 1_L.$$ Suppose that $\mid\uparrow\rangle ^{\otimes^L}$ (all spin ups) is one of the possible ground state configurations. What can be said about the ground state degeneracy?

My attempt: First, I considered the simple case of $L=2$; then $\hat{H} = \mathbf{\hat{S}}_1\cdot \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{2} = S_{1x}\otimes S_{2x}+S_{1y}\otimes S_{2y}+S_{1z}\otimes S_{2z}$ has eigenvalues $-3\hbar^2/4$ (multiplicity 1) and $\hbar^2/4$ (multiplicity 3).

Now we're given that $\mid \uparrow\uparrow\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ describes a possible ground state. It is an eigenvector of $\hat{H}$, with corresponding eigenvalue $\hbar^2/4$ (can be checked manually). So, the ground state is 3-fold degenerate. The state $\mid\uparrow\rangle ^{\otimes^L}$ can be represented as $(1\,0\,\dots\,0\,0)$, conaining $L^2$ components. I can see how the first column of the matrix of $\hat{H}$ would be this unit vector as well. I need to find the eigenvalues of $\hat{H}$ and their multiplicities. Since $\mathbf{\hat{S}}_i\cdot \mathbf{\hat{S}}_{i+1}$ will always contains the factor $\hbar^2/4$, I would essentially have to show that this is indeed an eigenvalue of $\hat{H}$ and I need to find its multiplicity. I don't really know how I would go about finding its multiplicity though. Any hints for this problem?

Comment: For L=2, you found the ground state is the unique antisymmetric singlet, no?

Comment: Looks like H should have a minus before the sum, otherwise |up,up> is not a ground state

Comment: It could be with an minus sign indeed. I found this problem online a few days ago, but can't find it back to check the exact expression.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a complete solution, I would just like to know how to handle these kinds of problems: you're given a Hamiltonian and a possible ground state, what can be said about the ground state degeneracy?

Comment: The ground state has  $L$ spins up. It is   a symmetric state and  therefore andeigenstate of $J_{\rm tot}$ with  eigenvalue $m= L/2$. It is therefore  the highest spin in an $j=L/2$ multiplet with dimension $2j+1$. So the degeracy is?

Comment: The degeneracy is $L+1$? Here, $J_{tot}$ refers to the total spin projection along the $z$-axis right? Amazing answer by the way, thank you very much, it really makes sense now to think of the spin ups as literal projections to end up with the corresponding $j$-multiplet.